# Suggestion to include CrossValidated SE in SO's off topic list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

Once the SO's off-topic list is not yet fulfilled, would it be possible to add CV SE to it?

[image]

I know it is not so frequent to have posts migrated from here to there, but it is at least common.

Maybe the logic is to include SE sites according to the number of posts that are migrated, but I am not sure if this rule is implemented yet, and if CV would appear among the first ones.

Thank's.

Comment: The standard andwer here is that "If you want to make this argument, show that <your suggested site> has more migration targets than other sites."  The list is manually set by the SE folks, but it does have the concept of 'most common = on the list' in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A follow up feature request was asked on Stack Overflow Meta and got approved: [Add CrossValidated to list of migration sites in the Close Dialog](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261072/add-crossvalidated-to-list-of-migration-sites-in-the-close-dialog).

Therefore, Cross Validated SE has been displayed in the Stack Overflow's migration dialog since August 2014.

Answer (score 3):

There is no extra slot. The dialog is just too big. <s>I believe its dimensions made more sense with our old close reasons that took up more space, but we can and probably should shrink it down some now.</s> It has to accommodate the duplicate finder UI, so we can't make it smaller.

Stack Overflow has the maximum number of migration paths already defined.

Comment: Why is there a line through the text in this post?

Comment: @AndreSilva 10k users can see the migration stats. You are quite wrong, [Tex.SE] has 5x the number of migrations that CV does. If there were another slot, it would be for [Codereview.SE]

Comment: In fact CR has 1.5x more migrations than Sharepoint, so if anything CR should be swapped in for it. (@adam)

Comment: Not surprising; TeX is almost-programming and used heavily by programmers, so you'd get a lot of those questions here :)  CV probably has a high percentage of migrations, compared to total questions here in R/SAS/SPSS/etc., but those pale to the other topics here.

Comment: @Kevin CR is still in beta and beta sites aren't eligible to be user-driven migration paths.