# No option in 'flag -> close -> off-topic -> belongs elsewhere' for migrate to stats.SE

Tags: feature-request, migration, statistics, migration-path-request

On Stack Overflow there a many questions pertaining to statistical software such as [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r).  Most of these questions are programming questions and undoubtedly belong on SO.  However, some questions are really about the underlying statistical ideas, and not about how to use R per se.  They belong on stats.SE (i.e., [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)).  However, when I flag such questions, CV is not listed with the other SE sites as an option.  **Can we add CV to that list?**

Comment: I think the new guidelines for voting on meta might be working.  2 days ago, this would have been downvoted into oblivion since it is an oft mention (and oft denied) request.

Comment: also relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189174/suggestion-to-include-crossvalidated-se-in-sos-off-topic-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Can we add CV to that list?**

**No**.

The list of quick-migration targets is purposely kept small. It is populated with the most common migration targets (except Programmers and Server Fault, which fought long and hard to get off it). 
On the list of actual migrations, CV is way down. Not even in the top 10.

Flag for moderator attention with a custom message explaining that it should go to CV.

Comment: I've tried that before & gotten the flag denied w/ the response that flags should not be used to send messages to moderators, that I should use the close -> off-topic, etc., path instead. However, there is no such path for stats.SE, so there is a catch 22 here.

Comment: If there's a quick-migrate target for the site, you should use it. What was the actual response you got? I would guess it's a canned one because the moderator didn't think that question was worth migrating, not because you didn't use a quick-migrate option.

Comment: The SO Q was: [linear model comparing predictive power of two different measurement methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235304/). My flag comment was: 'This question belongs on CV (ie, stats.SE). However, I didn't see that as an option under "it doesn't belong here, or is a duplicate".' The response was:  "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention". My impression was that I *was* trying to make the moderators aware of content that required their intervention (viz migrating).

Comment: I have just flagged another Q that belongs on CV, & I would prefer to do it in a way that doesn't create extra trouble for the moderators, but gets the information across efficiently.

Comment: That is a canned response, so for one reason or another that mod just didn't want to migrate that question, and choose that reason. It's not about flagging to migrate instead of a quick-migrate route.

Comment: That (flagging with a custom reason) is all that can be done for getting a question migrated where there's not a target for it. It's just part of the mods' job.