# Add Cross Validated to the "on-topic" Help Center page

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, vote-to-close, help-center, migration-path-request

Most of my Stack Overflow activity is devoted to R questions; in case anyone is not aware of R, it is an open-source statistical computing environment. Questions often get posted which are asking for what package to use for a vaguely describe problem. I try to refer people to CrossValidated.com where such questions are on-topic. Casting close votes is a bit of a pain because there is no radio button for CrossValidated.

The [Stack Overflow on-topic help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) does not recognize Cross Validated as a migration option, though I believe it to be such. I see that this has been requested before and at was rejected at least once. I hope that such a decision is not binding for all time; see [Suggestion to include CrossValidated SE in SO's off topic list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189174/suggestion-to-include-crossvalidated-se-in-sos-off-topic-list) **and** [Why flagging a post as off-topic doesn't include crossvalidated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179672/why-flagging-a-post-as-off-topic-doesnt-include-crossvalidated)

I now see that a more general approach was suggested and "declined". That suggestion was for some sort of tag-specific set of options for migration options. Seems that would create a method to ease the load on moderators by enabling a more one-click method for execution:

[Migrate shortlist based on tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68022/migrate-shortlist-based-on-tags)

What's the best way to assemble support for nominating modifications to the close panels and the on-topic page?

Comment: Where exactly should one be typing that phrase? (I am not aware of any voting process for migration.) Migration is different than closing.

Comment: Oh sorry, I **completely** misread this question.

Comment: By the way (as far as I know) - 4 (or 5) votes in `Close -> Off topic -> Belongs on another site -> The same site` triggers migration.

Comment: It might if it were in the list. I'm asking that CrossValidated be added to the list of sites to which migration can be requested. As far as I know there is not opportunity for "write-ins" and at the moment it is _not_ on the list.

Comment: @DWin Wait, do you want it to be available in the migration dialog or just in the help center? Those are two different requests.

Comment: Both, but I think it would be more useful to have it in the migration dialog (or to even allow for 'write-ins'). Perhaps there could be a list of boxed ( `[.]` ) codes to put in text entry box.)

Comment: Strongly support this; it is the most important sister-site for R/CV